# How can I print the output of pv each on a new line as it changes?

Tags: php, copy

I have to copy a large file using `pv` and since pv outputs progress, I want to take advantage of that and use it in a `php` file. However, `pv` outputs progress on the same line (overwriting the previous status) and I need it to write each new status on a new line, which then can be read by `php`.
How can I do that?
I've tried various versions of the following, but it doesn't work:

```
 pv largefiles > newlargefiles | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n'
```

Comment: Note that it might be easier to just [write your own copy function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834799/how-to-get-the-progress-status-of-the-copy-function-in-php).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474417/bash-pv-outputting-m-at-the-end-of-each-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that pv will do no output if stderr is not a terminal, so add `-f`. You also need to move stderr to the pipe:

```
pv -f largefiles 2>&1 >newlargefiles | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n'
```

Depending on your usage, you may not need the `stdbuf -oL`, as noted by @kos.

Comment: It works, just like I want it to. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: `As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid][askubuntu.com/help/…](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Comment: Nice answer, but may I suggest to remove the unuseful `stdbuf` wrapper? The output is "carriage return-buffered" already, translating carriage returns to newlines is enough: `pv -f largefiles 2>&1 >newlargefiles | tr '\r' '\n'`

Comment: @kos I agree that to a terminal you don't need the `stdbuf -oL`, but to a pipe you do (eg `|cat -vu`), and I'm not sure how the OP is using the command from php, and so what `tr` will decide. I added your suggestion, thanks.